# p:dialog closed regardless to condition in oncomplete

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I use JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.5

I have a dialog and in case if data not passed my validation rules not closed dialog

```
    <p:commandButton id="seasonSave" actionListener="#{adminSeasonController.add()}"
                             action="#{adminManageTournamentController.generateTournamentNames()}"
                             value="#{msg.save}" ajax="true"  
                             onmousedown="return validateSubmit('createSeasonForm', ['name_season'], 'lang')"                                                
                             oncomplete="if (#{not adminSeasonController.validationFailed}) addSeasonDialog.hide()"
                             update=":manageTournament:name_season, :manageTournament:title ,:menuForm:growl, @form">
```

I see in controller validationField = true, but dialog closed.

how I can resolve my problem?

Comment: You try:`oncomplete="if(#adminSeasonController.validationFailed})addSeasonDialog.show()`.

Comment: @Rong: EL in `on***` attributes of PF components are not evaluated on postback request, they are evaluated on initial request. They namely represent JavaScript code.

Comment: @BalusC hi, i didn't see `action` and the question, thank for your  attention :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look primefaces showcase for this problem.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf

Update of the link: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/loginDemo.xhtml

Comment: Link is broken :/

Comment: Add the proper link

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p:commandButton id="seasonSave" actionListener="#{adminSeasonController.add()}"
                             action="#{adminManageTournamentController.generateTournamentNames()}"
                             value="#{msg.save}" ajax="true"  
                             onmousedown="return validateSubmit('createSeasonForm', ['name_season'], 'lang')"                                                
                             oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) addSeasonDialog.hide()"
                             update=":manageTournament:name_season, :manageTournament:title ,:menuForm:growl, @form"/>
```